# Restrict a input to only specific character and 6 digit of numbers

Tags: jquery, regression

I want to restrict an input to only One Character (R) and 6 numbers only...
E.g: R123896

If Input length increase 7 it will remove that digit and if First word is not R , it should replace that character to "R"

I have written this script, but don't know how to move forward and shape it to what i want...

```
$("#consultationident").keyup(function(key){
var txtVal = $(this).val();  
 if(isNumber(txtVal) && txtVal.length>6)
 {
     $(this).val(txtVal.substring(0,6) )
 }
});
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

The use of a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) would be an idea...

```js
$("#consultationident").keyup(function(key){
  
  // Uppercase the first character.
  var firstChar = $(this).val().substr(0,1).toUpperCase();
  var rest = $(this).val().substr(1);
  
  $(this).val( firstChar + rest );
  
  var txtVal = $(this).val();
  var pattern = /^(R)(\d{6})$/;

  // Check if the value entered fits the pattern.
  if(pattern.test(txtVal)){
    console.log("Value ok");
  }else{
    console.log("Value wrong");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="consultationident">
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the code for validating input using regex

```
 $("#consultationident").keyup(function(key){
    var txtVal = $(this).val();  
    if(txtVal.length>6)
     {
       str =  $(this).val().substring(0,7);

       pattern = /^[a-zA-Z]{1}(\d{6})$/



       if(pattern.test(str)) {
         str = str.replace(/^[a-zA-Z]/,"R")   // Replace any character with "R"
         console.log(str);
    }
      else {
         console.log("invalid input");
      }
   }
});
```